# Uso de HttpClient en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo un problema:

Este es mi codigo del servicio

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class PhonesService {
  //esta es la ruta del archivo json con la data
  private urlPhonesData: string ='assets/data/phones.json';


  constructor(private _httpService: HttpClient) {

    console.log("Servicio de phones listo para usarse!!!!!");

  }

  //esta funcion hace el llamado a la data del archivo Json que tiene toda la informacion de los telefonos
  getPhones(){

    //el servicio _httpService nos regresa un observable  por lo que es un tipo de objeto anonimo el cual con la interface Phone le especificamos la forma en la que debe de regresar los datos al componente
    return this._httpService.get<Phone>(this.urlPhonesData);


  }

  getPhone(idx:string){

    //return this.phones[idx];

    console.log("Estes es el id que se recibe como parametro " + idx);

    return this._httpService.get<Phone>(this.urlPhonesData);
  }

export interface Phone{
  id:string,
  marca:string;
  box:string;
  metodo:string;
  detalles:string;
  timeunlock:string;
  img:string;
};
```

En la parte de la funcion  getPhone() quisiera mostrar solo los datos que coincidan con el Id del equipo, pero no se como poner eso en dicha funcion. Ya que tengo un componente el cual quiero que en la vista muestre solo el dato con el Id correspondiente.

Comment: ¿el método `getPhones()` devuelve un único objeto Phone? Algo no me cuadra, esperaría un array de objetos

Comment: @Socrasky Respondiendo la pregunta de Pablo podremos ayudarte mejor. No es bueno responder preguntas asumiendo cosas.

Comment: Bueno.
Mi idea es que la funcion getPhone() se le pase un parametro que seria el id de solo el objeto especifico que quiero mostrar en la vista, pero no se como mostrar esta informacion en la vista.

Comment: la funcion getPhones(), si me regresa un arreglo de telefonos, gracias a que esta ligado a un archivo Json con toda la informacion. espero me puedan ayudar con esto.

saludos.